# Area of circles: represent $x$ in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2$

Tags: geometry, circles

See the image. Area of green and red regions are equal. Can you represent $x=|O_2D|$ in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2$ for $r_1> r_2$ ?
[image]

Edit: The point $O_1$ does not enter in the region of small circle.

Comment: what is $x$‌‌‌?

Comment: We have to find $x$ :)

Comment: It is on the figure, but you may need sharp eyes to see it :)

Comment: It is the length of that "small perpendicular piece" that starts for the center of the smaller circle and "goes down a little."

Comment: @LordSoth exactly that is. Because of the resolution of the image, it is difficult to see.

Comment: [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) may help.

Comment: Why do we need $r_1>r_2$? Even with $r_1 = r_2$, $x$ is non-zero.

Comment: For $r_1<r_2$ the equal areas con not occur in the circle $O_2$. Maybe I can add $r_1\geq r_2$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Well, they can actually, if $\pi r_1^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}\pi r_2^2$, we are fine (in which case the entire blue region will disappear), but no problem, I was just curious about the condition.

Comment: Intuitively for $r_1$ slightly less than $r_2$, $O_1$ can divide $O_2$ in two equal parts. However, I am not sure so I just add $r_1>r_2$. And you are right, for $r_1=r_2$ the conditions satisfy.

Comment: My answer does not assume that the point $O_1$ enters the region of the small circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this pink rhombus:

[image]

If we split the green area into two sections (P and Q) along line M, we can find each of their areas in terms of the radius and angle of one of the circles, by subtracting the area of the triangle formed by the two radii and M from the area of the whole sector. (I'm going to use big $R$ for $r_1$ and little $r$ for $r_2$.)

$$ Area\space of\space P = \frac{\theta}{2\pi}{\pi{r^2}} - r^2\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}   $$
$$ Area\space of\space Q = \frac{\phi}{2\pi}{\pi{R^2}} - R^2\cos{\frac{\phi}{2}}\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}   $$

$$Area \space of\space Q + \space Area \space of \space P = \frac{\phi}{2\pi}{\pi{R^2}} - R^2\cos{\frac{\phi}{2}}\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}} + \frac{\theta}{2\pi}{\pi{r^2}} - r^2\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\pi {r^2}\tag{1}$$

That's four variables. We can relate $\theta$ to $\phi$ by expressing the length of $M$ in terms of each.
$$ 2r\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} = M = 2R\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}$$
$$ \phi = 2\arcsin{(\frac{r}{R}\cdot\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}})}\tag{2}$$
Pluging $(2)$ into $(1)$ should be sufficient to express $\theta$ in terms of $r$ and $R$.

Now, $x$ is $R$ less the length of the rhombus.
$$ x = R - r\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} - R\cos{\frac{\phi}{2}} $$
and the rest is algebra.