# Area of shaded region in terms of r

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

How to solve part iI? Can anyone give me explanation with an aid of diagram ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want area of shaded region or part 1 ?

Comment: Sorry it's part 2

Comment: very similar http://math.stackexchange.com/q/399827/218008

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint $AC=AB$ is the radius of the first circle and $BC=R$ is the radius of bigger one. So by pythagoras theorem $r^2+r^2=R^2$ thus $2r^2=R^2$ thus $R=\sqrt{2}r$. So yes now part $2$ see its $A_{circle}-(A_{semicircle}+A_{segment})=\frac{1}{2}\pi r^2-(\frac{1}{2}r^2(\frac{\pi\theta}{180}-sin(\theta)$. You can also construct a triangle and get area as $A_{sector}-A_{triangle}$